# HTML Contenteditable only on one line

Tags: javascript, css, html, markup

I have an app that has different lists a user can make, and the user can edit the name, but if he types a new name, he should be able to type enter and go many lines down.

I want to make the editable area only one line. I added a max height and overflow hidden, but that literally only hides what the other things you type, and I want only one line to stay.

code:

```css
h3 {
  height: 25px;
  max-height: 25px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<h3 contenteditable="true">To Do List</h3>
<section id="pageOne" contenteditable="true">
    <li style="color: #393939;"></li>
</section>
```

pictures:

[image]
[image]

Comment: You can try to add  `keydown` listener to you editable div, and if  `enter` key was pressed just `preventDefault()` that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As @TarasDanylyuk said, you can use `keydown` combined with `preventDefault()` to accomplish that.

Here's a working example:

```js
document.getElementById('pageOne').addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode == 13) {    // if Enter has been pressed
    e.preventDefault();
  }
});
```

```css
h3 {
  height: 25px;
  max-height: 25px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<h3 contenteditable="true">To Do List</h3>
<section id="pageOne" contenteditable="true">
  <li style="color: #393939;"></li>
</section>
```

If you want to remove focus when <kbd>Enter</kbd> is pressed, you can do so by adding this line after the `preventDefault()` call:

```
e.target.blur();
```

Comment: _If you want to remove focus when Enter is pressed_ You're a doggone mind reader!

Comment: Does this work if the user pastes multi-line text from the clipboard? Answer: It does not.